# Is it better to change "wash" into "washing"?

Tags: grammaticality

Please take a look at the following quote:

> “Happiness is a fatality,” wrote the poet Rimbaud. I remember being somewhat puzzled when I first read that line, **and then feeling a sense of ease and liberation wash over me**. Turning the idea of happiness on its head had suddenly made me very happy.
>
> -- [*Crazy Wisdom Saves the World Again!*](http://books.google.com/books?id=tYWpznye4SMC&pg=PA69&dq=%22and+then+feeling+a+sense+of+ease+and+liberation+wash+over+me%22&hl=ja&sa=X&ei=4yZFUqTZNqfYigKI04GgAg&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22and%20then%20feeling%20a%20sense%20of%20ease%20and%20liberation%20wash%20over%20me%22&f=false) by Wes "Scoop" Nisker, page 69.

Is it better to change *wash* into *washing*? Because I think this would be more suitable according to grammatical rules.

Comment: Again, man you don't need to give the link to the book. Instead, just quote the whole passage where the line is situated.

Comment: See [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10702/what-are-the-cause-and-effect-in-this-clause) for example.

Comment: A link to the book is welcome, however :-)  For starters, it lets us see additional context.  Sometimes it's difficult to tell exactly how much or how little you should quote...

Comment: @s, Agreed. However the fact we have to find ourselves where is a particular line placed, irritates me. In this kind of situations, he should at least say page no X (**At least**) and line no Y (_if possible_)!

Comment: Hello, Lincoln!  I've reformatted your question and made the link go straight to the original quote.  I think you could improve this question by explaining why you think it would be more suitable.  "Grammatical rules" is, unfortunately, rather vague.

Comment: @Mistu4u I got it, I will quote the whole passage where the line is situated.

Comment: @snailboat Hello! I just thought maybe the author wrote it in a wrong way.

Comment: @snailboat, Thanks for the formatting, it's better readable now :-) Lincoln, thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either can be correct. There's a very subtle difference in meaning, but neither is generally better than the other.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Neither _of them_", instead of "neither" only?

Comment: @Mistu4u Not necessary. "Neither" is a pronoun and can stand on its own; "of them" is just a prepositional phrase indicating which things are all excluded. In this case, it's clear from the context which options "neither" refers to.

Comment: I support you as far as retaining the same meaning is concerned. But you said there is a subtle difference. What is it?

Comment: @Mistu4u If I could articulate it, I'd have explained it. It has something to do with a difference in emphasis between a point-in-time event (wash) and a past-tense but less clearly defined experience (washing). Sort of the difference between preterite and aorist.

Comment: @Mistu4u, chrylis The technical category for the difference is *aspect*: *wash* expresses *perfective aspect* and *washing* expresses *imperfective aspect*. [This](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info) very sketchy treatment may help.